# Installing gcc-2.7.2 over an existing installation

Tags: gcc, installation, makefile

I am trying to install gcc-2.7.2 after reading the requirements for installing `Festival` [here](http://www.speech.cs.cmu.edu/festival/manual-1.4.1/festival_6.html#SEC13). On my workstation, I have gcc 4.4.1 installed. I am running into problems while running `make`. Here is how I am running `make`:

`make |& tee make.log`

The error message is as follows:

```
decl.c: In function ‘push_class_level_binding’:
decl.c:3606: error: lvalue required as increment operand
```

The offending line from `decl.c` is: `obstack_ptr_grow (&decl_obstack, x);`

The above function returns `void`. A look at the function definition in the file `obstack.h` shows:

```
#define obstack_ptr_grow(OBSTACK,datum)                 \
__extension__                               \
({ struct obstack *__o = (OBSTACK);                 \
   if (__o->next_free + sizeof (void *) > __o->chunk_limit)     \
     _obstack_newchunk (__o, sizeof (void *));              \
   if (!__o->alloc_failed)                      \
     *((void **)__o->next_free)++ = ((void *)datum);            \
   (void) 0; })
```

There is only one increment operation happening here. I am not sure how to change it to make the error go away. Or am I looking in the wrong place?

Any help is most welcome.

P.S: Please let me know in case more information is needed.

Comment: Don't do that. Try to compile your code with a recent GCC. If needed, patch teh Festival code. But 2.7.2 is a crappy compiler w.r.t. recent GCC 4.6 compiler.

Comment: I did. And ended up with this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8122478/declaration-of-void-abort-throws-different-exceptions - I tried pretty much everything and finally thought of re-installing a compiler that the Festival guys themselves suggest.

Comment: You can edit their code, and at least remove the -pedantic flag.

Comment: @Sriram: If the Festival folks suggest 2.7.2, their project would be completely abandoned for some reason. In fact, the [festival folks themselves say they support gcc 4.5](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/download.html). So, if you experience problems like in the other post, go ahead **and report them in the upstream**. This means the Festival developers. They have a contact page for good reason.

Comment: @thiton: That has to be a major D-OH! moment for me.. You are right, the gcc 2.7.2 version is for festival 1.4 while the version I have installed is 2.1 - which is also compatible with gcc 4.4. The docs that they have put up are for festival 1.4 (and they seem most complete and are returned as most relevant in search results). Since this seems like a non-question, I will delete this unless you want to make your comment into an answer..

Comment: @Sriram: You might save someone a similar d'oh moment if we leave this question undeleted :-).

Comment: Haha! Ok... I will leave this as is. Thanks for your reply.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the Festival folks suggest 2.7.2, their project would be completely abandoned for some reason. In fact, [the festival folks themselves say they support gcc 4.5](http://www.cstr.ed.ac.uk/projects/festival/download.html). So, if you experience problems like in the other post, go ahead and report them in the upstream.